# Regarding SaaS advantages

Tags: saas

I am going to work in SaaS Application. I want to know what are the advantages and why we are going to SaaS..Whether SaaS is an architecture like 3-Tier, MVC etc., or else it's a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a deployment and marketing technique than a software development methodology or architecture -- delivering "Software as a Service" instead of as a product.  On the plus side, it ensures an ongoing relationship between vendor and customer; on the minus side, it can be a painful lock-in for a client and a constant support headache for a vendor.

Google Apps is a prototypical example of SaaS -- it's an office productivity application that relies heavily on vendor-hosted functionality and is delivered via the Web.  Other forms of SaaS include pure-API services like PayPal Virtual Terminal which are intended to provide functionality to be integrated with a customer's existing line-of-business system.  In the degenerate case, even a fairly ordinary software application such as an electronic medical office software suite may be viewed as a partial SaaS offering because such software is nearly useless without a constant stream of updates delivered to account for the rapidly-changing pharmaceutical and billing landscapes.